# How to create custom page in magento2 which include one textbox and list off payment methods

Tags: magento2, payment, custom, page

I have created custom template where i just want to list out payment methods in magento2. I do not want to rewrite payment method block but fetch the same block in my custom template.Is there any example in magetno2 so i can do the same
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have only problem that how to load all payment methods in my custom page? I wan to load all payment methods as loaded on checkout page with all validation.(List of payment methods with default validation)

Answer (score 0):

I have idea. maybe help you.

1: create a module and your template in this module.
2: create page in cms and add code in content tab.

```
{{block class="Namespace\Modulename\Block\Blockname" template="Namespace_Modulename::vendor/tempalte_file_name.phtml" }}
```

in your block add 
`protected $_template Namespace_Modulename::vendor/tempalte_file_name.phtml`

Comment: Thanks for your replay, I did this thing. I have only problem that how to load all payment methods in this template? I wan to load all payment methods as loaded on checkout page with all validation.